# What is the origin of "settle your hash?"

Tags: etymology, idioms

I understand the phrase "settle your hash" means to subdue someone through the use of threats or violence. For example, a heated argument between two individuals where insults were being lobbed to and fro might lead one to exclaim:

> If you keep disparaging my mother like that I am going to settle your hash.

What is the origin of this idiom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

an early occurrence is from [Olympic Games by Isaac Cruikshank](http://www.bookrags.com/tandf/hash-tf/):

> 3. In settle (someone’s) hash, to subdue, silence, defeat; kill: s. >,
>      in C.20, coll. An early occurrence is
>      in Isaac Cruikshank, Olympic Games, 16
>      June 1803 (thanks to Mrs M.D.George).

it's also in *Americanisms: The English of the New World* (1872) by M. (Maximilian) Schele de Vere - here's an [image](http://books.google.com/books?id=peQIAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=americanisms+the+english+of+the+new+world&hl=en&ei=nla_TdacGZPAgQfKiPm_BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=settle%20one's%20hash&f=false):

[image: settle one's hash in Americanisms]

from [hash](http://dictionary.reference.com/etymology/settle+someones+hash):

> 1657, "to hack, chop," from Fr.
>   hacher, from O.Fr. hache "axe." The
>   noun "stew" is first recorded 1662,
>   from the verb.

My educated guess is that it's related to the the origins of the phrase ["bury the hatchet"](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2161/whats-the-origin-of-bury-the-hatchet), relevant quotes being:

> "Bury the hatchet" is an Indianism (a
>   phrase borrowed from Native American
>   speech). The term comes from an
>   Iroquois ceremony in which war axes or
>   other weapons were literally buried in
>   the ground as a symbol of newly made
>   peace. The other two languages spoken
>   by Europeans in close contact with the
>   Iroquois in and around what is now New
>   York state also use the phrase:
>   ***enterrer la hache de guerre*** and de
>   strijdbijl begraven. (I leave it as an
>   exercise for the reader to determine
>   which is French and which is Dutch.)

and

> The first mention of the practice in
>   English is to an actual
>   hatchet-burying ceremony. Years before
>   he gained notoriety for presiding over
>   the Salem witch trials, Samuel Sewall
>   wrote in 1680, "I writt to you in one
>   [letter] of the Mischief the Mohawks
>   did; which occasioned Major Pynchon's
>   goeing to Albany, where meeting with
>   the Sachem the[y] came to an agreemt
>   and buried two Axes in the Ground; one
>   for English another for themselves;
>   which ceremony to them is more
>   significant & binding than all
>   Articles of Peace[,] the hatchet being
>   a principal weapon with them."

So between MikeVaughan's answer that it's related to the French word for "axe" & the practice of "burying the hatchets", I'm inferring that "settle someone's hash" came from these ideas.

Comment: That's a nice bit of diligent research, but the problem is that I can't see how the definition of _hash_ you've given here fits at all with the idiom the OP's offered.  You mostly offered a verb whereas he's looking for a _noun_, and the _hash_ that's being offered certainly isn't a stew either.

Comment: @Billare I noticed that too. But still, nice research. I found the answer below after about 10 minutes of searching.

Comment: @Billare it's related to MikeVaughan's answer - don't want to elaborate much - the "brevity police" might be on the prowl! ;)

Comment: @Callithumpian thanks for the edit - I had access to that pix but I think it's being "clipped" by the system ...

Comment: @pageman: No problem. Check out the reference I just found. Could there be any Scottish connection?

Comment: @Callithumpian wow. how'd you find that? There might be a connection - maybe the earliest settlers who used this were of Scottish origin and started using this :)

Answer (score 5):

A ‘hash’ was a mess (from French ‘hachée’) and by ‘settling’ it, one sorted it out. It is also possible to make a hash (or mess) of something.

From: [Idiom Dictionary](http://www.idiomdictionary.com/definition/settle-someones-hash.html)

Comment: The OED says " to reduce to order; to silence, subdue; to make an end of, ‘do for’".

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=9sU2InvNCKsC&pg=PA3&dq=ajax%20his%20speech&hl=en&ei=E2K_TfnsKsHdgQeOmNnSBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=settle%20his%20hash&f=false) reference from a 1795 ([check](http://books.google.com/books?id=9sU2InvNCKsC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=m,dcc,xcv&f=false)) Scottish farce, *The Scottish Volunteers*—the subduing here being done by poison:

[image]

Comment: Aw, but that says "foon fettle his hafh", so it doesn't count!  <g>

Answer (score 0):

A variant spelling can be found earlier than 1795, in *The Politician Out-Witted*, a play written by Samuel Low in [1788](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29227/29227-h/29227-h.htm):

> Humphry. Well, if the case lies there, that **settles the harsh**, d' ye see; but, for my part, I think how you look old enough and ugly enough to be his great-grandfather, as the old saying is.

Cited by [1977](http://books.google.fi/books?id=EuvqPkAq2bkC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=%E2%80%9Csettles%20the%20harsh%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=1UolVhfFeD&sig=7RpbjYU2zHIfu0RlRuCEzHVudwk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6UpqT7jYLeX54QS95_TGCQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Csettles%20the%20harsh%E2%80%9D&f=false)'s *Early American Proverbs and Proverbial Phrases* by Bartlett Jere Whitin for this phrase, which, along with other folklorists, [praise the Humphrey character](http://books.google.fi/books?id=EuvqPkAq2bkC&pg=PR16&dq=%22The%20Politician%20Out-Witted%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c01qT-WqI-ag4gSv88z3CA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Politician%20Out-Witted%22&f=true) in the play as a good source of proverbs spoken:

> An anonymous play, *The Politician Out-Witted* (1788), contains a simple fellow named Humphrey who uses many proverbs and who himself attaches “as the old saying is” to things unproverbial as well as proverbial.